# Excel function to like XLOOKUP to return range

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have a data structure in excel where I want to generate a aggregated table based on a more detailed table based on some clustering e.g. Tasks -> Projects -> Investmentcluster.

In the aggregated projectoverview I use UNIQUE to get the list of Projects and then SUMIF and XLOOKUP to get sums or the first value from the original table columns I am interested in.

However I have one column, where I need all the entries beeing found concatinated. I would use something like concat(filter(l, x: x == "pName")) in programming languages. I already found the CONCAT function... but how do I get another function that returns a range I can feed into CONCAT?

**Orignal Sheet**

| Project | Task | Invest | Description |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| P1 | T1 | 1 | ABC |
| P1 | T2 | 1 | ABC |
| P1 | T3 | 1 | ABC |
| P1 | T4 | 1 | ABC |
| P2 | T5 | 1 | ABC |
| P2 | T6 | 1 | ABC |
| P2 | T7 | 1 | ABC |

**Target Sheet**

| Project | Invest | Description |
| --- | --- | --- |
| P1 | 4 | ABC, ABC, ABC, ABC |
| P2 | 3 | ABC, ACB, ABC |

My problem lies in the Description column.

Greetings,
Xlaech

Comment: Please include sample input in markdown format and expected results.

Comment: @JvdV I added an orginal and a target table.

Comment: So within the invest column is an aggregated SUM of the original data too?

Comment: Yes. All columns are aggregations. The aggregation functions would be SUM, FIRST and CONCAT.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have a go with:

[image]

Formula in `F1`:

```
=REDUCE(INDEX(A1:D1,{1,2,4}),UNIQUE(A2:A8),LAMBDA(x,y,VSTACK(x,HSTACK(y,SUMIF(A2:A8,y,C2:C8),TEXTJOIN(", ",,REPT(D2:D8,A2:A8=y))))))
```

Comment: =TEXTJOIN(CHAR(10);;UNIQUE(REPT(<searchrange>;<valuerange>=<searchtern>))) was perfekt <3 Can you explain why REPT is working? I thought this would just repeat given characters?

Comment: @Xlaech `REPT()` is repeating the characters here based on the binary values, see `A2:A8=y` where `y` is `UNIQUE(A2:A8)`

Answer (score 1):

I think this also would work:

```
=LET(y,A2:A8,z,UNIQUE(y),HSTACK(z,SUMIF(y,z,C2:C8),BYROW(z,LAMBDA(x,TEXTJOIN(", ",1,FILTER(D2:D8,y=x))))))
```

[image]

Or if you want formula only for column `C` using already predetermined columns `A` and `B`:

```
=TEXTJOIN(", ",1,FILTER(D2:D8,A2:A8=A11))
```

[image]